# How to resize the Legend Item Wndow in Map Composer?

Tags: qgis, cartography, print-composer, legend, user-interface

I am just wondering if there is any simple way (no messing with codes) to adjust this Legend Item Window in Map Composer. I am using QGIS 2.14 in windows 8.

A much larger (taller) window would really help, rather than this 2-cm window that is so hard to scroll when you have 20+ legend items to edit.

Here is the screenshot of the Map Composer

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Not sure it's currently possible but if you want, you can increase your 2cm window to a **4cm window** by moving the *Atlas generation* dock window somewhere inside the middle of the *Legend* window. This should turn the *Atlas generation window* into a menu tab:

[image: Moving dock window]

Now you should have a little more space but not a huge amount:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in the upcoming version 2.14.2.